# ObjectAnimator leaves remnant

Tags: android, animation

Has anyone else used ObjectAnimator to change the position of View elements? Does it leave remnants on the screen for you too?

Check out above middle button. The blue box just animated from there and left remnants, screen tearing, or fragments. How are you guys handling this?

[image]

Code if it matters:

```
public class AnimateComponentsActivity extends Activity {

private View box;   
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    box = findViewById(R.id.box);
    box.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("TEST", "Box got a click");

        }
    });

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
}


private View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("TEST", "Animation should be playing");

        // new way, but can't scale size
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(box, "y", v.getY()).start();
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(box, "x", v.getX()).start();
        ValueAnimator.ofObject(new WidthEvaluator(box), box.getWidth(),   v.getWidth()).start();

    }
};

private class WidthEvaluator extends FloatEvaluator {

    private View v;
    public WidthEvaluator(View v) {
        this.v = v;
    }

    @Override
    public Object evaluate(float fraction, Object startValue, Object endValue)         
        {
        Float num = (Float)super.evaluate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = Math.round(num);
        v.setLayoutParams(params);
        return num;
    }
}
}
```